# Java Integer.ParseInt bug

Tags: java, arrays, string, int, parseint

Initial string = `61440 <CARRE> 150 381 188 419 </CARRE>`

I've split this string into an array, which now contains the coordinates

```
String[] coord = t.group(2).split(" ");
```

The resulting output was :

```
les coord est :150 381 188 419
i = 0 et sa valeur est :150
i = 1 et sa valeur est :381
i = 2 et sa valeur est :188
i = 3 et sa valeur est :419
```

for which I did a for loop:

```
formeCoord = new int[coord.length];
formeCoord[i] = Integer.parseInt(coord[i]);
```

Now I'd expect an output with an int array with all the coordinates.  But instead the output is :

```
Voici la valeur de i =0 et sa valeur int: 0
Voici la valeur de i =1 et sa valeur int: 0
Voici la valeur de i =2 et sa valeur int: 0
Voici la valeur de i =3 et sa valeur int: 419
```

Here is the for loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i<formeCoord.length; i++){
    System.out.println("Voici la valeur de i ="
        + i
        + "et sa valeur int: "
        + formeCoord[i]);
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you populated your array (i.e. `formeCoord`) correctly?

Comment: Post the for loop..

Comment: Well when i system.printout the array "coord" it show's up correctly.

Comment: I mean the loop where you set up formecoord. Most likely dukeling's answer is correct but you havent posted the relevant bit of code.

Comment: Not that for loop, the other one. The one containing these lines: `formeCoord = new int[coord.length]; formeCoord[i] = Integer.parseInt(coord[i]);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you're creating a new array every iteration, instead of adding to it.

Presumably your code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < coord.length; i++)
{
  formeCoord = new int[coord.length];
  formeCoord[i] = Integer.parseInt(coord[i]);
}
```

You need to change it to:

```
formeCoord = new int[coord.length];
for (int i = 0; i < coord.length; i++)
  formeCoord[i] = Integer.parseInt(coord[i]);
```

Comment: You could set up your IDE to put every variable/Object that can be final to final. It would have helped to find this bug

Answer (score 2):

If you are looping over the following code...

```
formeCoord = new int[coord.length];
formeCoord[i] = Integer.parseInt(coord[i]);
```

you are resetting formeCoord every time apart from the last time it gets run